# How to change the default value of shortcode_atts

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array, wordpress-shortcode, genesis

How change the default value of shortcode_atts.

Here is the function code that iam trying to change default value of shortcode_atts using add_filter.

```
function author_of_posts($atts) {

    $defaults = [
        'after' => '',
        'before' => '',
    ];
    $atts = shortcode_atts($defaults, $atts, 'post_author');

    $output = sprintf('%1$s<span class="author">%2$s</span>%3$s',
        $atts['before'],
        the_author(),
        $atts['after'],

    );

    return apply_filters('the_author_shortcode', $output, $atts);
}
```

Here iam trying to change default shortcode_atts value, using add filter.

```
add_filter('the_author_shortcode', 'change_shortcode_atts');

function change_shortcode_atts() {
    $atts['before'] = 'Writer';
    return $atts;
}
```

Comment: In what context is your function called?

Comment: Check now updated question.

Comment: I can't make any sense of what you are doing there. `author_of_posts` appears to be a shortcode callback function itself - but then it should return the rendered content, but instead you are returning the $atts array out of `change_shortcode_atts`.

Comment: author_of_posts is theme function not mine.  change_shortcode_atts is my function  that  i want to change default value using add filter.

Comment: You can't just change the `atts` like this. The filter is filtering the `output` but passing the `atts` your filter should essentially copy the entire `author_of_posts` content, but pass the `atts` that you need.